# \backmatter not working - showing page numbers

Tags: thesis

I've started with the basic structure for my thesis, but the \backmatter command doesn't seem to work and there are arabic page numbers on all the pages of the backmatter (however the \frontmatter is working as expected). What might have I done wrong?

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, lmargin = {2.7cm}, rmargin = {2.9cm}, tmargin = {2.7cm}, bmargin = {4.6cm} ]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

    \include{./misc/titlepage}
    \include{./misc/abstract}
    \tableofcontents

\mainmatter 
    \input{./chapters/chapter1}

\backmatter 
   \bibliographystyle{geralpha}
   \bibliography{./bib/references}
   \input{./misc/acronyms}
   \input{./misc/annex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome, is \backmatter supposed to change the page numbering?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible). That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: BTW, I strongly suggest not to eliminate page numbers in the backmatter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing fine! It is indeed the proper behavior of `\backmatter`. From the KOMA documentation:

> The back matter is introduced with `\backmatter`. Opinions differ as to
>   what belongs in the back matter. So in some cases you will find only
>   the bibliography, in some cases only the index, and in other cases
>   both of these as well as the appendices. The chapters in the back
>   matter are similar to the chapters in the front matter, but page
>   numbering is not reset. If you do require separate page numbering, you
>   can use the `\pagenumbering` command in section 3.12, page 84.

Comment: Ah, I thought it was supposed to remove the page numbering, because references, appendix etc. don't require enumeration. Thank you for all the information and I will try and make my code compilable from now on!

Comment: Have a good time writing your thesis! Please consider upvoting and marking as ‘Accepted’ the answers you receive on this site by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).